# Creating R package containing a dataset and an R function which uses the data

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package containing a dataset and an R function which uses the data.
The R function looks like this:

```
myFun <- function(iobs){

            data(MyData)
            return(MyData[iobs,])

           }
```

When I do the usual "R CMD check myPack" business, it gives me error saying

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
myFun: no visible binding for global variable ‘MyData’
```

Is there way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lazy-loading for this.

Just put

`LazyData: yes`

in your DESCRIPTION file and remove

`data(MyData)`

from your function. 
Due to lazy-loading your MyData-Object will be available in your namespace, so no need for to call data().

Answer (score 4):

Two alternatives to the lazy data approach. Both rely on using the `list` argument to `data`

`data(list = 'MyData')`

---

#### Define as an default argument of the function (may not ideal as then can be changed)

```
myFun <- function(iobs, myData = data(list='MyData')){


  return(myData[iobs,])

}
```

---

#### Load into an empty environment then extract using `[[`.

```
myFun2 <- function(iobs){
  e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  data(list='MyData', envir = e)
  e[['MyData']][iobs,]

}
```

Note that 
`e$MyData[iobs,]` should also work.

I would also suggest using `drop = TRUE`as safe practice to retain the same class as `MyData`
eg 
`MyData[iobs,,drop=TRUE]`. This may not be an issue given the specifics of this function and the structure of `MyData`, but is good programming practice, especially within packages when you want robust code.